# What was the idiomatic way of reverse traversal of an iterable before C++11?

Tags: c++

```
void rev(string& str)
{
    for (auto i = str.end() -1; i != str.begin() -1; i--)
        cout << *i;

    cout << '\n';
}
```

The code above works on my system however `str.begin() -1` invokes undefined behaviour as per the standard. So what is the idiomatic way of reverse traversal using *iterator*'s but not *reverse_iterator*'s?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator

Comment: btw what's issue with `reverse_iterator`? that's the idiomatic way to traverse in reverse order.

Comment: So what is the idiomatic way besides the idiomatic way?

Comment: The issue with `reverse_iterator` is that it wasn't available before C++11. That may become a problem when someone does not have a compliant compiler.

Comment: Are you under the impression that ```reverse_iterator``` is a C++11 feature? Because it is not.

Comment: Homer512 I see, that may be my mistake.

Comment: `reverse_iterator` has been in ALL C++ standards.  In fact, it was introduced in the STL (which existed before the first C++ standard was ratified, and influenced design of the standard library).

Comment: If for some reason you do not want to use `reverse_iterator`, you could use `rbegin()` and `rend()` instead

Comment: `end()-1` would be also UB in case of empy range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
for (auto i = str.end(); i != str.begin(); )
{
    --i;
    ...
}
```